# Trigonometric Substiution

Tags: trigonometric-integrals

I am currently working on a practice problem on trig substitution.

I have no problem solving it my way but I don’t see how i can use the below stated identity and partial integration.
(I am sorry i am not using mathjax, im looking into it but it is quite confusing for me)

[image]

And here is my solution. [image]

I tried rewriting as 1- sin^2(theta), but when i attempt to use partial integration it just does not solve, and I have no idea how to rewrite it.

Many thanks for your help

X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts: $u=cos\theta,\ dv=cos\theta d\theta$, therefore $du=-sin\theta d\theta,\ v=sin\theta$.  Result, $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}cos^2\theta d\theta=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}sin^2\theta d\theta$, since $cos{-\frac{\pi}{2}}=cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}=0$

$2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}cos^2\theta d\theta=2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}sin^2\theta d\theta$.  The two integrals sum to $2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta=2\pi$.

Therefore the integral in question $=\pi$.

Comment: Many thanks that the exercise should contain integration by parts

Comment: @Petra I revised answer to include integration by parts.

Comment: wow many thanks that you took the time I would have never seen this